# Python summing up values in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary P which represents a dictionary within a dictionary within a dictionary. It looks something like this.

```
P={key1:{keyA:{value1: 1, value2:3}, keyB:{value1:3,value2:4}}, 
key2:{keyA:{value1: 1, value2:3}, keyB:{value1:3,value2:4}}, key3{...:{...:}}}
```

What I am trying to do is to write each value of value1,value 2 in terms of their percentages of the totalPopulation from whichever is there base key.

For example key1 should look like

```
key1:{keyA:{value1: 1/(1+3+3+4), value2:3/(1+3+3+4)}, keyB:
{value1:3/(1+3+3+4),value2:4/(1+3+3+4)}
```

What I am not sure about is how to iterate over this dictionary and only collect the innermost values of a certain key so I can then sum up all the values and divide each value by that sum.

Comment: there can any level of nesting or is it fixed?

Comment: @Ashish Ranjan It is a fixed level of nesting, but not a fixed number of values. There will always be keyA and keyB, but the dictionary corresponding to those keys can have any number of values

Comment: please show more of your code. also if your keys or value names are not referencing already instantiated objects, they should be **strings**

Comment: @Leyton any feedback? did it work?

Comment: @Ashish Ranjan Yes thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in single line using dict `comprehension` and `map` like this:

```
#from __future__ import division # use for Python 2.x
p = {"key1":{"keyA":{"value1": 1, "value2":3}, "keyB":{"value1":3,"value2":4}}}

p = {kOuter:{kInner:{kVal: vVal/sum(map(lambda x: sum(x.values()), vOuter.values())) for kVal, vVal in vInner.iteritems()} for kInner, vInner in vOuter.iteritems()} for kOuter, vOuter in p.iteritems()}
```

A more readable version of above :

```
p = {
        kOuter:{
            kInner:{
                kVal: vVal/sum(map(lambda x: sum(x.values()), vOuter.values())) for kVal, vVal in vInner.iteritems()
            } 
            for kInner, vInner in vOuter.iteritems()
        } 
        for kOuter, vOuter in p.iteritems()
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> p
>>> 
{'key1': {'keyB': {'value2': 0.36363636363636365, 'value1': 0.2727272727272727}, 'keyA': {'value2': 0.2727272727272727, 'value1': 0.09090909090909091}}}
```

The only problem with this is that the sum is calculated repeatedly, you can fix that by calculating the sum for each of your `key1`, `key2`... before this dict comprehension and use the stored values instead, like this :

```
keyTotals = {kOuter:sum(map(lambda x: sum(x.values()), vOuter.values())) for kOuter, vOuter in p.iteritems()}
```

and then you can simply access the sums calculated above by keys, like this:

```
p = {kOuter:{kInner:{kVal: vVal/keyTotals[kOuter] for kVal, vVal in vInner.iteritems()} for kInner, vInner in vOuter.iteritems()} for kOuter, vOuter in p.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test = {"key1":{"keyA":{"value1": 1, "value2":3}, "keyB":{"value1":3,"value2":4}}}

for a in test:
        s = 0
        for b in test[a]:
            for c in test[a][b]:
                s += test[a][b][c]
        print(s)
        for b in test[a]:
            for c in test[a][b]:
                test[a][b][c] = test[a][b][c] / s
```

This should do what you want. I've only included "key1" in this example.